# How to create an array from json ionic

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

Below is the data i get from the rest API

```
{
   "memberdetails":[
      {
         "id":46,
         "customername":"Zack",
         "phoneno":"1323223232",
         "nickname":"Zack",
         "regdate":"2017-12-27 18:38:36.185829",
         "groupname":"Test group",
         "regid":36,
         "groupdesc":"Test Test test",
         "groupicon":"new",
         "tamount":"3100"
      },
      {
         "id":46,
         "customername":"Carol",
         "phoneno":"254721493487",
         "nickname":"Caro",
         "regdate":"2017-12-28 23:47:22.317687",
         "groupname":"Test",
         "regid":36,
         "groupdesc":"Test Test Test",
         "groupicon":"new",
         "tamount":"130"
      }
   ]
}
```

From the above data i want to populate 2 arrays as i want to plot a graph in the below format. The lineChartData array should pick the tamount and the lineChartLabels Array should pick the customenames. Thank you.

```
public lineChartData:Array<any> = [{data: [15, 29, 24, 21, 26, 15, 10], label: 'Opening/Time'}];
public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ["Dan","Were","Kibe","Zack","Evah","Chris","Jess"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('testapp', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function(){
    this.inputData = {
      "memberdetails": [
        {
          "id": 46,
          "customername": "Zack ",
          "phoneno": "1323223232",
          "nickname": "Zack ",
          "regdate": "2017-12-27 18:38:36.185829",
          "groupname": "Test group ",
          "regid": 36,
          "groupdesc": "Test Test test ",
          "groupicon": "new ",
          "tamount": "3100"
        },
        {
          "id": 46,
          "customername": "Carol ",
          "phoneno": "254721493487",
          "nickname": "Caro ",
          "regdate": "2017-12-28 23:47:22.317687",
          "groupname": "Test ",
          "regid": 36,
          "groupdesc": "Test Test Test ",
          "groupicon": "new ",
          "tamount": "130"
        }
      ]
    };
    
    this.expectedOutput = {
      "lineChartData": [
        {
          "data": [
            15,
            29,
            24,
            21,
            26,
            15,
            10
          ],
          "label": "Opening\/Time"
        }
      ],
      "lineChartLabels": [
        "Dan",
        "Were",
        "Kibe",
        "Zack",
        "Evah",
        "Chris",
        "Jess"
      ]
    }
    
    this.computedLineChartData = [{data:[],label:"Opening\/Time"}];
    this.computedLineChartLabels = [];

    for(var i=0;i<this.inputData.memberdetails.length; i++){
      var curMember = this.inputData.memberdetails[i];
      this.computedLineChartData[0].data.push(curMember.tamount);
      this.computedLineChartLabels.push(curMember.customername);
    }
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="TestCtrl as tc">
<pre>{{tc|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, however am getting this error when trying to plot the graph
VM175 GroupdetailsPage.ngfactory.js:133 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at BaseChartDirective.updateChartData

if i hardcode the data e.g. this.computedLineChartData = [{data:[45,77,78],label:"Opening\/Time"}]; the graph is showing without an error.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs we have function like angular.fromJson(data) which returns output in form of array . So you can easily convert json to array.